# Django update an object using models.Field object

Tags: django, model, field

I have dozens of fields in a Django model.

```
class Question(models.Model):
op1 = models.CharField(verbose_name="Option 1",max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
op2 = models.CharField(verbose_name="Option 2",max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
op3 = models.CharField(verbose_name="Option 3",max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
....
```

I want to write a function

```
def update_ith_option_of_question( q, i, val):
     op = d._meta.get_field('op'+str(i))
     # I want to save val in field op of object q
```

How do I write the above function?

Answer (score 1):

Use Python's `setattr`.

```
def update_ith_option_of_question(q, i, val):
    setattr(q, f'op{i}', val)
    q.save()
```

Also, using `f''` strings for formatting is more readable.